# Facebook login flow with to nodejs

Tags: node.js, facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am working on a REST API backend service for an app that uses both email and facebook login. Lets just pretend this app is a todo list app and a user can sign in and add notes which they could later view on may different devices.

The "Login with email" is pretty simple, the app would make a request to:

```
URL: /v1/login
Params: email, password
```

Then the serivce returns an access token if all this information is correct so we know the identity of the user creating, updating or deleting a note/list item.

Now for the facebook side. I've seen several differnet answers all over StackOverflow and Facebook's documentation. Some people say, just pass in the id and login the user with the matching id. This would mean calling the login function from the Facebook SDK and just keeping that id to send in a request.

```
URL: /v1/login/facebook
Params: id
```

That would work but seems highly unsecure. Anyone could get  someone else's Facebook id and just send a request to the server. Facebook's documentation mentions also using the account email. We'll what if the user ever changes their email on Facebook, they could never login to this app again. Another hint of security would be passing in the token from Facebook every time. Since those tokens can change or expire, there really wouldn't be a way login past the expiration date.

The final method I know of would be passing in the app secret:

```
URL: /v1/login/facebook
Params: id, secret
```

This seems by far the most secure, if you are using https to connect to the server. The downside to this method is, what if the Facebook secret token is ever reset? I mean you could always make a call to the server to request and check if token was reset and if so pass back the new one. But then if anyone had access to the endpoint to check out of date tokens, it could give them the new secret token.

I know we are dealing with the internet here and there will always be security flaws and there isn't a **perfect** way to do this. But what is the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Try to send facebook_token for that user.
    URL: /v1/login/facebook
    Params: facebook_token

and service side make a service call to facebook graph api to get information about that user using facebook_token.

get the facebook id from that response and use it to provide data to that user.